# Issue with searching an array for an object based on its properties. (In JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have been designing a program to help make the task of subnetting networks particularly easier. Right now, all it is SUPPOSED to do is search through an array and pull out the object that matches the properties the user defines. Currently, I am having an issue where only the first object in the array is chosen regardless of the user's choice.

Note: Also, whenever I input a value greater than 1 for "subnets" it gives me my error 280. Class A is the only one that even works in general.

So, if anyone knows how I can properly search for my desired objects (not only for "subnets" but for the other 3 options) how would I do this?

I apologize, this code is atrocious and has many flaws! I just cannot wrap my head around what I have done wrong, nor how to fix it. I have only been programming for maybe a few months and this is my biggest project by far.

Please test this and see what I have done wrong. The main test environment I have used is Codecademy's JavaScript interpreter.

Thank you guys for any suggestions and or solutions you may have!

```
//This program was developed by N1njaMDN.

//This program's purpose is to help assist with subnetting.

/*This section of the code is designated to holding all the subnet information.
All of the data is put into an object in the format of
{subNumA:#,
subNumB:#,
subNumC:#,
hostNum:#,
BlockSize:#,
customSubMask:"#.#.#.#"}
*/

/*To find block size, we subtract (the first portion of the custom subnet mask from the left that isnt a 255)
from 256. Example: in 255.192.168.1, we would do 256-192. This number is our block size.*/

var objects = [
{
    cidr:8,
    subNumA:1,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:16777214,
    blockSize:256,
    customSubMask:"255.0.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:9,
    subNumA:2,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:8388608,
    blockSize:128,
    customSubMask:"255.128.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:10,
    subNumA:4,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:4194304,
    blockSize:64,
    customSubMask:"255.192.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:11,
    subNumA:8,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:2097152,
    blockSize:32,
    customSubMask:"255.224.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:12,
    subNumA:16,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:1048576,
    blockSize:16,
    customSubMask:"255.240.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:13,
    subNumA:32,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:524288,
    blockSize:8,
    customSubMask:"255.248.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:14,
    subNumA:64,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:262144,
    blockSize:4,
    customSubMask:"255.252.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:15,
    subNumA:128,
    subNumB:0,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:131072,
    blockSize:2,
    customSubMask:"255.254.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:16,
    subNumA:256,
    subNumB:1,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:65536,
    blockSize:256,
    customSubMask:"255.255.0.0"
},

{
    cidr:17,
    subNumA:512,
    subNumB:2,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:32768,
    blockSize:128,
    customSubMask:"255.255.128.0"
},

{
    cidr:18,
    subNumA:1024,
    subNumB:4,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:16384,
    blockSize:64,
    customSubMask:"255.255.192.0"
},

{
    cidr:19,
    subNumA:2048,
    subNumB:8,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:8192,
    blockSize:32,
    customSubMask:"255.255.224.0"
},

{
    cidr:20,
    subNumA:4096,
    subNumB:16,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:4096,
    blockSize:16,
    customSubMask:"255.255.240.0"
},

{
    cidr:21,
    subNumA:8192,
    subNumB:32,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:2048,
    blockSize:8,
    customSubMask:"255.255.248.0"
},

{
    cidr:22,
    subNumA:16384,
    subNumB:64,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:1024,
    blockSize:4,
    customSubMask:"255.255.252.0"
},

{
    cidr:23,
    subNumA:32768,
    subNumB:128,
    subNumC:0,
    hostNum:512,
    blockSize:2,
    customSubMask:"255.255.254.0"
},

{
    cidr:24,
    subNumA:65536,
    subNumB:256,
    subNumC:1,
    hostNum:256,
    blockSize:256,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.0"
},

{
    cidr:25,
    subNumA:131072,
    subNumB:512,
    subNumC:2,
    hostNum:128,
    blockSize:128,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.128"
},

{
    cidr:26,
    subNumA:262144,
    subNumB:1024,
    subNumC:4,
    hostNum:64,
    blockSize:64,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.192"
},

{
    cidr:27,
    subNumA:524288,
    subNumB:2048,
    subNumC:8,
    hostNum:32,
    blockSize:32,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.224"
},

{
    cidr:28,
    subNumA:1048576,
    subNumB:4096,
    subNumC:16,
    hostNum:16,
    blockSize:16,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.240"
},

{
    cidr:29,
    subNumA:2097152,
    subNumB:8192,
    subNumC:32,
    hostNum:8,
    blockSize:8,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.248"
},

{
    cidr:30,
    subNumA:4194304,
    subNumB:16384,
    subNumC:64,
    hostNum:4,
    blockSize:4,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.252"
},

{
    cidr:31,
    subNumA:8388608,
    subNumB:32768,
    subNumC:32,
    hostNum:2,
    blockSize:2,
    customSubMask:"255.255.255.254"
}
];
var classGiven = prompt("What is the class of your given network address?").toLowerCase();
var addressGiven = prompt("What is your given network address?");
var userChoice = prompt("What is your given information? ('subnets', 'hosts', 'subnets & hosts', or just a 'network address'?) Type your answer based on what is between the quotes.");
switch(userChoice) {
//This section is for showing info based on number of subnets only.
case 'subnets':
    var subnetsNeeded = prompt("How many subnets do you need?");
    switch(classGiven) {
    //This is only for class A subnets.
        case 'a':
            function getObjectsAsub(subnetsNeeded) {
                var obj, i, il;
                for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
                    if (objects[i].subNumA >= subnetsNeeded) {
                        obj = objects[i];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong! error280");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var objectArrayTwo = obj;
                console.log(obj);
            }
            getObjectsAsub(subnetsNeeded);
            break;
    //This is only for class B subnets.
        case 'b':
            function getObjectsBsub(subnetsNeeded) {
                var obj, i, il;
                for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
                    if (objects[i].subNumB >= subnetsNeeded) {
                        obj = objects[i];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong! error298");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var objectArrayTwo = obj;
                console.log(obj);
            }
            getObjectsBsub(subnetsNeeded);
            break;
    //This is only for class C subnets.
        case 'c':
            function getObjectsCsub(subnetsNeeded) {
                var obj, i, il;
                for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
                    if (objects[i].subNumC >= subnetsNeeded) {
                        obj = objects[i];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong! error316");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var objectArrayTwo = obj;
                console.log(obj);
            }
            getObjectsCsub(subnetsNeeded);
            break;
    //This is the default case.
        default:
            console.log("Something went wrong! error327");
            break;
    }
    break;
//This section is for showing info based on number of hosts only.
case 'hosts':
    var hostsNeeded = parseInt(prompt("How many hosts do you need?"));
    var exactHostsNeeded = hostsNeeded + 2;
    function getObjectsHost(exactHostsNeeded) {
        var obj, i, il;
        for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
            if (objects[i].hostNum >= exactHostsNeeded) {
                obj = objects[i];
                break;
            } else {
                console.log("Something went wrong! error342");
                break;
            }
        }
        var objectArrayTwo = obj;
        console.log(obj);
    }
    getObjectsHost(exactHostsNeeded);
    break;
//This section is for showing info based on number of subnets and hosts only.
case 'subnets & hosts':
    var subnetsNeeded = parseInt(prompt("How many subnets do you need?"));
    var hostsNeeded = parseInt(prompt("How many hosts do you need?"));
    var exactHostsNeeded = hostsNeeded + 2;
    switch(classGiven) {
    //This is only for class A subnets.
        case 'a':
            function getObjectsA(exactHostsNeeded, subnetsNeeded) {
                var obj, i, il;
                for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
                    if ((objects[i].hostNum >= exactHostsNeeded) && (objects[i].subNumA >= subnetsNeeded)) {
                        obj = objects[i];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong! error366");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var objectArrayTwo = obj;
                console.log(obj);
            }
            getObjectsA(exactHostsNeeded, subnetsNeeded);
            break;
    //This is only for class B subnets.
        case 'b':
            function getObjectsB(exactHostsNeeded, subnetsNeeded) {
                var obj, i, il;
                for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
                    if ((objects[i].hostNum >= exactHostsNeeded) && (objects[i].subNumB >= subnetsNeeded)) {
                        obj = objects[i];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong! error384");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var objectArrayTwo = obj;
                console.log(obj);
            }
            getObjectsB(exactHostsNeeded, subnetsNeeded);
            break;
    //This is only for class C subnets.
        case 'c':
            function getObjectsC(hexactHostsNeeded, subnetsNeeded) {
                var obj, i, il;
                for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
                    if ((objects[i].hostNum >= exactHostsNeeded) && (objects[i].subNumC >= subnetsNeeded)) {
                        obj = objects[i];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong! error402");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var objectArrayTwo = obj;
                console.log(obj);
            }
            getObjectsC(exactHostsNeeded, subnetsNeeded);
            break;
    //This is the default case.
        default:
            console.log("Something went wrong! error413");
            break;
    }
    break;
//This section is the default for the main switch!
default:
    console.log("Something went wrong! error419");
    break;
}
```

Comment: first pointer, never define function inside switch case.  Define outside and call it in switch.  Also I see functions like `getObjectsAsub, getObjectsBsub`. They can be handled in same function like `getObjectsSub(className)`. Similarly you can so same for `getObjectsA`.

Comment: Can you please provide us with some inputs and then expected output for those inputs, please?

Comment: @GlenKeane one input scenario for "subnets & hosts" would be a class C. Where I need about 4 hosts and 32 subnets. It should return all the information from CIDR29 because that is the best fit. (We need at least 4 hosts, but the amount of usable hosts is hosts-2, so the 8 total hosts - 2 would give us 6 which is still more than enough so it would work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll reiterate my comment, define functions outside and call them in switch case.

```
case 'b':
    function getObjectsBsub(subnetsNeeded) {
        var obj, i, il;
        for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
            if (objects[i].subNumB >= subnetsNeeded) {
                obj = objects[i];
                break;
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Something went wrong! error298");
                break;
            }
        }
        var objectArrayTwo = obj;
        console.log(obj);
      }
      getObjectsBsub(subnetsNeeded);
  break;
```

Secondly, if you see you condition,

```
        for (i = 0, il = objects.length; i < il; i++) {
            if (objects[i].subNumB >= subnetsNeeded) {
                obj = objects[i];
                break;
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Something went wrong! error298");
                break; // This is why only first object is selected
            }
        }
```

Also I took the liberty to modify function per my understanding,

```
function getObjectsSub(classType, subnetsNeeded) {
    var obj;

    objects.forEach(function(row){
        if(row["subNum" + classType] >= subnetsNeeded){
            obj = row;
            return;
        }
    });

    if(!obj){
        console.log("Something went wrong! error280");
    }

    var objectArrayTwo = obj;
    console.log(obj);
}
```